# Are there any reducing agents for reduction of nitrobenzene to aniline other than Sn/HCl?

Tags: organic-chemistry, aromatic-compounds, nitro-compounds, organic-reduction

I was taught that Sn/HCl should be used for reduction of nitrobenzene to aniline. Can I ask if there are any alternative reducing agents (for example, LiAlH4?) to do the same task?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hydrogenation of aromatic nitro groups (over, for example, $\ce{Pd/C}$) usually results in reduction to the corresponding aniline and is probably easier to carry out and work up as compared to $\ce{Sn/HCl}$.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reduction_of_nitro_compounds#Aromatic_nitro_compounds) has a list of several conditions for reduction of $\ce{ArNO2}$ to $\ce{ArNH2}$.  It also states that $\ce{LiAlH4}$ reduces it to the azo compound $\ce{ArN=NAr}$, which is corroborated by March's *Advanced Organic Chemistry* (7th ed.).

In any case, from a practical perspective, you would probably want to avoid using $\ce{LiAlH4}$ if there's a simpler alternative. It's dangerous and the workup is not fun.

Comment: Hydrogenation would always be my preferred conditions because of the ease of running and working up. My second choice was tin (II) chloride in EtOAc at reflux.

Comment: Can I ask if you have any idea why do my school's notes state that H2(g) with Pt(s) is not able to reduce nitrobenzene? Has there been a shift in the consensus brought by, for example, the publication of certain papers)?

Comment: @TimingLiu they're probably simply wrong, as hydrogenation over Pd or Pt is very common. https://doi.org/10.1016/B978-0-12-395532-6.50014-3 *"Aromatic nitro groups are easily hydrogenated to the corresponding
aromatic amine. Palladium or platinum catalysts are by far the most used
in these reductions; rhodium and ruthenium catalysts have as yet found
only limited and specialized use. The reductions occur readily under mild
conditions and usually without complication."* This was written in 1967.

Comment: I agree with @orthocresol, the notes are just wrong. I've used Pt on C many times to reduce a range of aromatic nitro groups. AFAIK this is done on an industrial scale.